# how to restrict git merge PR using a different user?

Tags: git, github

Is there a solution to setup in a repo to force git merge PR using a different user who initialize the PR?

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Short answer: No. GitHub does not offer this. The only thing that’s necessary to merge a pull request is collaborator status (i.e. that you can close *any* issues and push changes).